# Porque debo instanciar ciertas clases?

Tags: javascript, clase

*Porque la clase `string` ***no debo*** instanciarla para usar una función de su prototipo? , ejemplo:*

```js
String.prototype.mayus = function(){
  
  return this.toUpperCase();
  
};

var frase = "mayusculas".mayus();
console.info(frase);
```

Ahora si quiero usar una funcion de la clase `Number`, **debo instanciarla**

***SIN INSTANCIA:***

```js
Number.prototype.restar = function(d){
  
  return d + (-d);
  
};

var b = restar(5);
console.info(b);
```

*CON INSTANCIA:*

```js
Number.prototype.restar = function(d){
  
  return d + (-d);
  
};
var k = new Number();
var b = k.restar(5);
console.info(b);
```

Comment: Solo como comentario, es una muy mala práctica agregar funciones a los prototipos de objetos primitivos

Comment: Por que carlos? y de donde te basas?

Comment: No solo de objetos primitivos sino de cualquier clase que no sea tuya. De lo contrario así como tu modificas prototipos de otras clases otro código puede estar también agregando su propia versión  de `restar` por ejemplo y podría estar llamandose a esa en lugar de la tuya. Básicamente se rompe con el encapsulamiento

Comment: En el ejemplo **SIN INSTANCIA** estas creando el prototipo `Number.prototype.restar` pero cuando lo invocas lo estas haciendo "al aires", es decir no hay un numero u objeto number que este llamando a restar `var b = restar(5);`, en resumen si restar le pertenece a un numero, un numero debe de invocar a restar `var b = AQUI_TIENE_QUE_IR_UN_NUMBER.restar(5);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el caso de string no la instancias porque ya tienes una instancia: `"mayusculas"`

En el caso de Number no necesitas crar otra instancia puedes llamar a la función  `restar` directamente sobre `5`

```js
Number.prototype.restar = function(d) {
    return d + (-d); // Esta línea no tiene sentido pero quien soy yo para juzgar...
};

var b = (5).restar(5);
console.info(b);
```

Ten en cuenta que el primer `5` no es tomado en cuenta por la función restar, solo el parámetro (segundo 5) por lo que lo siguiente deveulve el mismo resultado:

```js
Number.prototype.restar = function(d) {
    return d + (-d); // Esta línea no tiene sentido pero quien soy yo para juzgar...
};

var b = (100).restar(5);
console.info(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

te falta agregar el ejemplo parecido a la cadena; la unica diferencia con respecto a la cadena es el `this.valueOf`

```js
Number.prototype.duplicar = function(){
   return this.valueOf() + this.valueOf()
  
};
Number.prototype.restar = function(d){
   return this.valueOf() -d;
  
};
var numero =4;
console.info(numero.duplicar());


var numero2 = new Number(10);
console.info(numero2.duplicar());
console.info((100).duplicar());


console.log("resta primer valor:" + numero.restar(5))
console.log("resta segundo valor:" + numero2.restar(5))
console.info("resta sin usar variable" + (100).restar(3));
```

En el ejemplo que tu tienes estas esperando un parametro llamado **`d`**

```
Number.prototype.restar = function(d)
```